# FIFO Pipelining Server only receiving certain amount

Tags: c, client-server, pipeline, mkfifo

So I'm trying to implement a basic FIFO pipeline in C using mkfifo().
Here are my code classes so far:

main.c:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
char *path = "/tmp/fifo";
pid_t pid;

setlinebuf(stdout);
unlink(path);
mkfifo(path, 0600);

pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) {
    client(path);
} else {
    server(path);
}

return(0);
}
```

client.c:

```
void client(char *path) {

char *input;
input = (char *)malloc(200 * sizeof(char));

read(STDIN_FILENO, input, 200);

struct Message message;
message = protocol(input); //protocol simply takes an input string and formats it
char number = message.server;
char* string;
string = message.string;

int fd;

fd = open(path, O_WRONLY);
write(fd, string, sizeof(string));
printf("Client send: %s\n", string);
close(fd);


return;
}
```

server.c:

```
void server(char *path) {
int fd;
char *input;
input = (char *)malloc(200 * sizeof(char));

fd = open(path, O_RDONLY);
read(fd, input, sizeof(input));
printf("Server receive: %s\n", input);
close(fd);

return;
}
```

Now the pipeline is working, but for some reason the server only receives part of the message. For example if we get the following string from the protocol: "HELLO WORLD" We get the following output:

```
Server receive: HELLO WO
Client send: HELLO WORLD
```

The server should receive the whole message, but it isn't. What am I doing wrong? Thank you for any help!

Comment: In server.c, why `input = (char *)malloc(200 * sizeof(char));` but then `read(fd, input, MAX_BUF);` when `MAX_BUF` is 1024?

Comment: Oh right I was trying various things, and both having that MAX_BUF or using sizeof(input) gave me the same output. Guess I forgot to change it back to something consistent! ^^;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice you have skimped the usually essential checking of return values from `open` and `read` and `write`. If you had, you might have noticed the error in this line

```
write(fd, string, sizeof(string));
```

Because `string` is a pointer, you are sending 8 bytes (the size of the pointer). You should use `strlen(string)` or that `+1`, depending on whether the terminator needs to be sent.

```
write(fd, string, strlen(string));
```

You repeat the mistake in your recent unwise edit:

```
read(fd, input, sizeof(input));
```

You would be better sticking with the original `#define` and using that for both buffer allocation and read request size.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm still very new to C. Using strlen and going back to my previous MAX_BUF did the trick!!

Comment: Please try to avoid in-line hard coded magic numbers - always source them from a single definition.